# How does webkit find libflashplayer.so?

Tags: linux, flash, ubuntu, webkit, gtk

I use webview in webkitgtk to open a html file to play flash files on server in my code. But it suggest me that Missing Plug-in. So I want to know how webkit finds libflashplayer.so and what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

The plugin search path on Unix systems is defined in the WebKit source code at `WebKit/Source/WebKit2/Shared/Plugins/unix/PluginSearchPath.cpp`. Currently it loads plugins from the following locations:

```
$MOZ_PLUGIN_PATH
$MOZILLA_HOME/plugins
$HOME/.mozilla/plugins
$HOME/.netscape/plugins
/usr/lib/browser/plugins
/usr/local/lib/mozilla/plugins
/usr/lib/firefox/plugins
/usr/lib64/browser-plugins
/usr/lib/browser-plugins
/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins
/usr/local/netscape/plugins
/opt/mozilla/plugins
/opt/mozilla/lib/plugins
/opt/netscape/plugins
/opt/netscape/communicator/plugins
/usr/lib/netscape/plugins
/usr/lib/netscape/plugins-libc5
/usr/lib/netscape/plugins-libc6
/usr/lib64/netscape/plugins
/usr/lib64/mozilla/plugins
/usr/lib/nsbrowser/plugins
/usr/lib64/nsbrowser/plugins
```

So WebKitGTK+ will find `libflashplayer.so` if it is installed to one of those locations.

Answer (score 0):

It is in `/usr/lib/flashplugin-installer`

fullt path:

```
/usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so
```

Comment: Yes,I found libflashplayer.so in the path:/usr/lib/flashplugin-install/.     But I still can't open html files which have flash files in it.What should I do? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Yes I copy libflashplayer.so to /usr/lib/mozlla/plugins  and it works.Thank you very much for your help!